# PLS-00201 (12: 16): PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.myid' must be declared

Tags: oracle, triggers

Im trying to create one trigger for update event. But getting below exception.

```
[Error] PLS-00201 (12: 16): PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.myid' must be declared
```

myid is available in table employee_tbl.

```
IF UPDATING THEN 
    if (new.myid <> OLD.myid) then

  UPDATE Employee_tbl SET
   ROLE_ID=null,
   SEC_ID=null
 WHERE USER_OBJID=:OLD.USER_OBJID;

end if;
```

Comment: try put : before new an old

Comment: show us the trigger's source

Comment: You have to use `:old` and `:new`, with`:`.